# Issue with missing "request" in django function

Tags: python, django, request

I have a little question about request attribute in my function located in a python file (not my view):

```
def my_function(model, request):
    instance = model.objects.filter(application=request.cur_app, display=True).order_by('order')
    return instance
```

In this same file, I call my function like this:

```
for element in my_function(my_model):
     ... do something ...
```

But I get this issue:

```
my_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I don't understand How I can solve this issue, because if I add 'request' in my loop, I get:

```
name 'request' is not defined
```

Thank you !

**Update:**

I have a middleware.py file which contains this:

```
class MultiSiteMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.cur_app = WebApplication.objects.get_current(request)
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And this is this middleware that I want to get in my menu.py file in this function:

```
def list_of_edition():
    """ Return list of editions
    :return queryset
    """
    instance = NavbarMenuSettings.objects.filter(application=MultiSiteMiddleware, display=True).order_by('order')
    return instance
```

Comment: As per the function definition `def my_function(model, request):` the request argument is required. How does the request argument get passed into `my_function` in other places of this function invocation?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I tried to add `request` when I call this function (just one time in my code), but through this way, request is not defined. The only place where my function is called corresponds to my example with the for-loop

Comment: `request` object is injected by Django automatically in your view. If you really need the request object in other python files or functions, then the easiest way is to just pass the request object from `view` to other places.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Any example to share in order to see what I have to write exactly ?

Comment: You can't access request object globally or in some other function not taking request as param. You can only access it inside a functions receiving it as param. Can you elaborate more on your exact need for it to access globally?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I brang a modification in my question, but I'm bit lost

Answer (score 0):

When you run this function

```
my_function
```

you must given two params model and request

```
model = ...
request = ...
my_function(model,request)
```

Answer (score 0):

django function base view 1st positional argument is request,

def funtionbaseview(request, arg1, arg2)

Comment: I'm not in the views.py file.